# cobc: Invalid argument error when compiling

Tags: gnucobol

I'm currently taking up  a course in COBOL and recently I have only been using an online compiler. When I decided to install the OpenCOBOL IDE. I keep getting the error "cobc: Invalid argument" whenever i try to compile. I tried multiple re-installs still to no avail. I also tried installing just the compiler itself and compiling my files using cmd, but still it gives that error. Any help? I really need to get it working.

OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: Could you post the command you are using? -- Hint error messages usually mean exactly what they say -- You are not passing the correct arguments to cobc on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need an "-x" option to tell the compiler build an executable with the same name as the program source (but without the .cbl or a "-o progname" option to tell the compile to produce an executable named progname.

Comment: like cobc -x filename.cbl? (tried that still same error)